# Reducing Query Load Times By Limiting Results on Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following scope.

```
public function scopeWithPosts($query)
{
    return $query->with(
        ['posts' => function($query)  {
            $query->limit(2);   // Line 5
        }]
        // further eager loads
        // e.g. ['posts.*']
    );
}
```

My relationship is as follows:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Models\Post', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

I am attempting to do the above to reduce the load time on my query. Problem is that whenever I attempt limit, it doesn't seem to work.

For example, with Line 5 I get 1 result, and if I remove I get 5 results.

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tested the take method?

```
$query->take(2);
```

For even more precise limitation you could use

```
$query->skip(10)->take(2);
```